# Providing my Ruby program as an all-in-one installer

Tags: ruby, windows-installer

I have written a short program in a ruby file that runs correctly on my PC. However I need to find a way to give this to my colleagues to use. They have no knowledge of ruby. The program requires various non standard gems. What is the best way to provide them with a one click installer for my program, including all the gems and ruby itself.

Comment: What do you mean by non-standard gems ?

Comment: Stuff that doesn't come with the ruby install. like Watir... and anemone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [OCRA](http://rubyforge.org/projects/ocra/) - it packages everything into a single executable (no installation required).

When you run the executable, it extracts everything into a temporary directory (including the ruby interpreter) and runs your script from this directory.

Comment: For [more alternatives](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/packaging_to_executables.html) from the ruby toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

I havn't use it (so I don't know if it works), but you can try to use [RubyScript2Exe](http://www.erikveen.dds.nl/rubyscript2exe/)

Comment: AFAIK, Rubyscript2Exe doesn't work with recent Ruby versions due to an error in command line parameter handling ("string XYZ is frozen"), but it's been a while since I last tried it. /UPDATE/ The GitHub fork mentioned in Ocaj's comment apparently fixes this.